# jQuery.animate() in a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, jquery-animate

I have the following code:

```
$("." + selectedOption + ":eq(0)").show().animate({
    left: 0 + $(".option1:visible").outerWidth(),
    opacity: 1
}, 700, function() {
    $("." + selectedOption + ":eq(0)").animate({
        top: 0
    }, 700);
});
```

This works just as I want it to... but I want to repeat this animation numerous times over, each time animating the next "selectedOption", i.e. :eq(1), :eq(2), :eq(3).  So I thought putting the above code within a for loop would work:

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    //code here
}
```

When I did it doesn't work.  Any ideas why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the foor loop use https://api.jquery.com/each/ and you will need to change that that :eq()

Or simply add class to the item which you have to animate and remove it after finishing it

Answer (score 0):

You need a recursive function. Something like this:

```
var count = 0;
function animateNextOption() {
  $("." + selectedOption + ":eq(" + count++ + ")").show().animate({
    left: 0 + $(".option1:visible").outerWidth(),
    opacity: 1
  }, 700, animateNextOption);
}
animateNextOption();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.queue()` , `.promise()`

```js
var selectedOption = "selectedOption";

$({}).queue("_fx", $.map($("." + selectedOption), function(el) {
  return function(next) {
    return $(el).animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 700, function() {
      $(this).animate({
        top: 0
      }, 700)
    }).promise().then(next)
  }
})).dequeue("_fx")
```

```css
.selectedOption {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="selectedOption">1</div>
<div class="selectedOption">2</div>
<div class="selectedOption">3</div>
```